# Problem regarding proving a real valued function to be continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

My question is -

> Let, $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Define
>   $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ by $$ g(x)= \begin{cases} f(a), & \text{when}\quad
>  x=a\\ \operatorname{sup}_{(a,x]} f, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
>   Prove that $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

I am able to prove the continuity of $g$ at $a$ in the following manner-
By continuity of $f$ at $a$, we get - for any $\varepsilon>0\exists\ \delta>0$such that $f(a)-\varepsilon<f(x)<f(a)+\varepsilon\ \forall x\in(a,a +\delta)$.
Thus for any $x\in(a,a +\delta)$, we have $f(a)-\varepsilon<\operatorname{sup}_{(a,x]} f<f(a)+\varepsilon\implies|g(x)-g(a)|<\varepsilon\ \forall x\in(a,a +\delta)$, since $f(a)=g(a)$, done.

Now, I want to work with the reamining $(a,b]$. So,
I take a point $x_0\in(a,b]$ and $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
Choose $\varepsilon>0$. Then for this $\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ such that $f(x_0)-\varepsilon<f(x)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon\ \forall x\in(x_0 -\delta,x_0 -\delta)$.
My claim is - $g(x_0)-\varepsilon<g(x)<g(x_0)+\varepsilon\ \forall x\in(x_0 -\delta,x_0 -\delta)$ or equivalently $\operatorname{sup}_{(a,x_0]} f-\varepsilon<\operatorname{sup}_{(a,x]} f<\operatorname{sup}_{(a,x_0]} f+\varepsilon\ \forall x\in(x_0 -\delta,x_0 -\delta)$.
But I can't prove it rigorously.
Can anybody complete my proof? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: Your idea can be easily completed into a full proof. Just note that $\sup_{x\in(c-\delta, c+\delta) } f(x) $ lies between $f(c)$ and $f(c) +\epsilon$. Now compare $f(c) $ and $g(c) $ and note that $g(c) \geq f(c) $. I am using $c$ instead of $x_0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, this way I can get $g(x)\leq g(c)+\varepsilon\forall x\in(c-\delta, c+\delta)$. But how to show $g(c)-\varepsilon<g(x)\forall x\in(c-\delta, c+\delta)$?

Comment: If $g(c) =f(c) $ then from last comment it follows that $|g(x) - g(c) |<\epsilon $. If $g(c) > f(c) $ then we can choose $\epsilon$ such that $f(c) +\epsilon<g(c) $ and then $g(x) =g(c) $ and proof is complete.

Comment: No what I have written is correct without any typos.

Comment: How $f(c)+\epsilon<g(c)\implies g(x)=g(c)?$ And does $x\in(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ here?

Comment: You may have a look at the answer given in linked question.